# Object detection+tracking

Tags: opencv, object-detection, yolo

I am new in the field of CV and trying to build an object detection with yolo and object tracking with DeepSort.
I have some problems with the identification of objects in the video. Here an example:
The sport ball is identified in the video but when it is too close to the person, the detector can not identify it.

In this picture the Ball is identified:

[image]

Here the bull is not identified:

[image]

How can I improve the detection? I am using pre-trained yolov3(which is trained on the coco dataset) and DeepSort.

Answer (score 2):

To get a better accurancy from yolov3 you can retrain the model with new images.

If you don't want to do that, maybe you can try to upgrade your model and use Yolov4 or Yolov5. These has better perfomance and accurancy.

https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5

Answer (score 0):

Based on the resolution of your sample, I can say that it's a crop from much larger image, therefore the ball in its given context it's fairly small object.

Yolo architectures are notorious for poor performance on small objects due to their reduced dimensionality in the feature maps.

For tracking detecting and further tracking small objects I recommend using an [SSD](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.02325.pdf) architecture which uses to feature maps extracted from multiple depth levels for producing the results; or maybe try out a newer architecture that can equal inference time performance such as [EfficientDet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.09070.pdf). Implementations for both of them can be found over a variety of frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single object tracking when it is not detected. In OpenCV: KCF, CSRT etc.

Frame N. Detected 2 objects: person and ball. Save pointer to the Frame N.

Frame N+1. Detected only person. Create single tracker (CSRT is better) for previous ball position on Frame N. Run CSRT tracker on current Frame N+1. Get current position and add it to the detections. Save pointer to the Frame N+1.

Frame N+2. If ball was detected then delete CSRT tracker. Save pointer to the Frame N+2.

...